# Use one query or several queries to PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, tornado, postgresql-9.3, momoko

I have the following DB

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    user_uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    user_name CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    token_id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unique_thing (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    unique_thing_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    option_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    variable INTEGER NOT NULL,
    variable_2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    char_var CHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    char_var2 CHAR(512),
    char_var3 CHAR(256), 
    file_path CHAR(256) NOT NULL
);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS different_option_of_things (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name CHAR(64)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS commits (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    unique_thing_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    value REAL NOT NULL, 
    var CHAR(512) NOT NULL, 
    example_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    boolean_var boolean NOT NULL
);
```

The tables `unique_thing`, `different_option_of_things` and `examples` will be static (the data will be added rarely and manually).
The table `commits` will be rather large. It will be the table for insert only (I will delete very rarely).
The user will be the table with user idnetification. It will be not so large as `unique_thing`, but will have quite a few users.

The Data of the table will be as follows:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES(1, 'pacefist', 2);
INSERT INTO users VALUES(3, 'motherfucker', 4);
INSERT INTO users VALUES(4, 'cheater', 5);

INSERT INTO different_option_of_things   VALUES(1, 'blablab');
INSERT INTO different_option_of_things   VALUES(2, 'smth different');
INSERT INTO different_option_of_things   VALUES(3, 'unique_thing');
INSERT INTO different_option_of_things   VALUES(4 ,'unique_thing2');

INSERT INTO unique_thing  VALUES(DEFAULT, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO unique_thing  VALUES(DEFAULT, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO unique_thing  VALUES(DEFAULT, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO unique_thing  VALUES(DEFAULT, 2, 2);

INSERT INTO example VALUES(1, 20, 20, 'fsdfsdf', 'fgdfgdfg', 'url', '/home/user/file.txt');
INSERT INTO example VALUES(2, 24, 40, 'sfadfadf', 'dfgdfg', 'url', '/home/user/file2.txt');

INSERT INTO commits VALUES(DEFAULT, 1, 1, 55.43, '1234567', 1, TRUE);
INSERT INTO commits VALUES(DEFAULT, 2, 1, 97.85, '1234573', 2, TRUE);
INSERT INTO commits VALUES(DEFAULT, 3, 1, 0.001, '98766543', 1, TRUE);
INSERT INTO commits VALUES(DEFAULT, 4, 2, 100500.00, 'xxxxxxxx', 1, TRUE);
```

So, the data will be inserted ther following way:

```
1) I have input data of different_option_of_things, e.g.,  [ blablab, unique_thing],  the REAL value (like 8.9999) and the number of example like `fsdfsdf`
2) It's necessary to find this record in the table `unique_thing`
a) if we've found 2 or more values or haven't found anything 
    results false -> the search is over
b) if we've found 1 result then 
    3) we are searching all values (record from unique_thing) in the 'commits' table. 
     a) if it has been found 
        a.1 search of the given example name
          a.1.1 if found -> get first 25 values and check whether the current value is bigger
               a.1.1.1 if yes, we make a commit
               a.1.1.2 if no, do nothing (do not duplicate the value)
          a.1.2 no -> no results
        a.2 if no -> no results
```

The second function will be almost the same but without insertion, we will just make a selection without insertion (only to get data) and will find for all existing values in the table 'examples' (not only one).

The question: is it better to create 3 functions instead of one big query?

```
SELECT count(1) AS counter FROM different_option_of_things 
        WHERE name IN (SELECT * FROM unnest(different_option_of_things));

SELECT * FROM example where id=fsdfsdf;

SELECT TOP 25
    FROM commits
    JOIN unique_thing
    ON commits.id=unique_thing.unique_thing_id where value > 8.9999;

if results-> 0 do a commit
```

Or is it better to write one enormous query? I am using Postgresql, Tornado and momoko.

Comment: There are a few foreign key constraints missing from your DDL, so it seems.

Comment: I'd recommend stored procedures, each to get and set data - the logic depends only on db data. From momoko it will be only one call (execute)

Comment: so is it better to call one execute or several?  I can create it but i am worrying about perfomance

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer two stored procedures each to get and insert data.

Pros:

- all required data is in db, so it seems like a job for db,
- each call on execute needs to:

  1. get/wait for available connection in pool (depending on your app)
  2. run query
  3. fetch data
  4. Release connection

     x. And between all of this operation on IOLoop

  Although momoko is non-blocking, it is not for **free**
- db can be api, not only sack of data

Cons:

- logic in db means you depend on it - change db engine (for example to cassandra) will be harder
- often logic in db means there is no tests. Of course you can and you should  test it (e.g.  [pgTap](http://pgtap.org/))
- for simple tasks it seems like a overkill

It is matter of db and app load, performance and time constraints - in other words run tests and choose solution that meets your expectations/requirements.